# Session Id + change password, best practice

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, sessionid, change-password

on our web-store (Java, Hybris) a user has an opportunity to change a password.
According to the best vulnerability practice should we change SessionId or leave the old one or maybe create a new Session? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

A User want to reset the password when

- Suspects account compromise
- Routinely changes the password thinking of security practice or force by the system policy

I would suggest to logout all the current user sessions on the password reset. Also, it's a good idea to implement a mechanism to confirm the user's identity like secure code SMS/email, reset password link over email, etc. Which distinguishes between the legitimate user and an attacker.

Yes, it may not be a good user experience.

Read a more [detailed answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/178669/172418).